# Read Json file with Scala/Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a json, example:

```json
{
  "id1": {
    "a": "7",
    "b": "3",
    "c": "10",
    "d": "10",
    "e": "15",
    "f": "11",
    "g": "2",
    "h": "7",
    "i": "5",
    "j": "14"
  },
  "id2": {
    "a": "3",
    "b": "7",
    "c": "12",
    "d": "4",
    "e": "10",
    "f": "4",
    "g": "13",
    "h": "4",
    "i": "1",
    "j": "13"
  },
  "id3": {
    "a": "10",
    "b": "6",
    "c": "1",
    "d": "1",
    "e": "13",
    "f": "12",
    "g": "9",
    "h": "6",
    "i": "7",
    "j": "4"
  }
}
```

when I process it with spark.read.json ("file.json") it returns a single record with this format:

```
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|id1                                |id2                                    |id3                              |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|{7, 3, 10, 10, 15, 11, 2, 7, 5, 14}|{322539, 7, 12, 4, 10, 4, 13, 4, 1, 13}|{10, 6, 1, 1, 13, 12, 9, 6, 7, 4}|
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

I would like the result to be something like this when processing the file:

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 | col10 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id1 |  7   |  3   |  10  |  10  |  15  |  11  |  2   |  7   |  5   |  14   |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id2 |  3   |  7   |  12  |  4   |  10  |  4   |  13  |  4   |  1   |  13   |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id3 |  10  |  6   |  1   |  1   |  13  |  12  |  9   |  6   |  7   |  4    |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

some simple and fast way?

thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to modify your input JSON file ? If so, making it an array of JS Objects would do the job with spark.read.json() :

```
[    
    {
      "id": "id1",  
      "a": "7",
      "b": "3",
      "c": "10",
      "d": "10",
      "e": "15",
      "f": "11",
      "g": "2",
      "h": "7",
      "i": "5",
      "j": "14"
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for what the solution would like this assuming this change was made?

Comment: I can't edit it, I receive it like this, in that format.

Comment: How big is this file that you are reading it with spark? If it's not big then read it with some json lib, and then create the df after processing it. If it's really big, you have a problem. Btw, afaik, array of json objects wouldn't work either
"Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object. For more information, please see JSON Lines text format, also called newline-delimited JSON." (in here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html)